# No response from Ubuntu One Oauth request

Tags: ubuntu-one, php, ubuntu-one-api

According to the documentation at https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud, I should be able to get files with 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1/~/Ubuntu One', but temporarily renamed to 'https://files.one.ubuntu.com/~/Ubuntu One'. I'm getting no response from either, though my access token is successful and I'm able to get:

```
object(stdClass)[230]
  public 'visible_name' => string 'Username'
  public 'root_node_path' => string '/~/Ubuntu One' (length=13)
  public 'user_node_paths' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'resource_path' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'user_id' => int number
  public 'max_bytes' => int number
  public 'used_bytes' => int number
```

Is there something wrong with the server or my account?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at passing a querystring of include_children=true to see the contents of the Ubuntu One folder.

For reference, when I make a request to https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1/~/Ubuntu%20One this is the JSON I get back:

```
 {
    "kind": "directory", 
    "when_created": "2009-02-11T15:33:10Z", 
    "generation": 12592, 
    "has_children": true, 
    "content_path": "/content/~/Ubuntu One", 
    "generation_created": 0, 
    "parent_path": null, 
    "is_live": true, 
    "resource_path": "/~/Ubuntu One", 
    "when_changed": "2013-01-23T15:56:45Z", 
    "key": "(removed)", 
    "path": "/", 
    "volume_path": "/volumes/~/Ubuntu One"
  }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the above with a sample of the actual JSON. Perhaps you could show the JSON you receive back?